# how to set tag or id for Exoplayer MediaSource?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, exoplayer-media-item, android-media3

I am using `Exoplayer` for playing multiple audio files.

We can set media an Id when creation using:

```
MediaItem.Builder()
   .setUri(uri)
   .setMediaId("my_unique_id")
```

and get media Item id in `onMediaItemTransition` listener using `mediaItem.mediaId`.

```
val playerListener = object : Player.Listener {


    override fun onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem: MediaItem?, reason: Int) {
        super.onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem, reason)
        val id =  mediaItem?.mediaId
    }
```

in my use case, I must use `MediaSource` instead of `MediaItem`.
how can I set media source a tag or id and get it in `onMediaItemTransition`?